# How to restore a deleted OAuth client

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have mistakenly deleted an OAuth client, now my Apps Script in my Google sheet is requiring authorization, can someone help me?

I created a new OAuth client but don't really understand what I need to do with the stuff generated.

Comment: Did you try agreeing to the terms of the authorization popup?

Comment: Is this a published Add-on/web app or a bound script within your Google sheets you are working with?

Comment: It is a script bound in to me Google sheet.

Comment: The popup informed me the OAuth had been deleted

Comment: I found a solution. I saved my Google sheet as a copy, then ran the script(s) from that, and then the popup requested me to allow the script access. This I did and everything is running as before. The previous sheet then renamed, and the new sheet renamed to what it was before. Lesson learnt.